# Entity framework 6 - include operation returns only first row for 3rd level related object

Tags: .net, linq, entity-framework-6

I am trying to retrieve related nested objects using include command but i get only first row for the 3rd and 2nd level nested object.

```
public class PtaSetDetail
{
    public decimal SetDetailId { get; set; }

    public decimal SetId { get; set; }      

    public decimal CaseSeq {get; set;}

    public decimal CaseId { get; set; }       

    public PtaCase PtaCases { get; set; }
}

public class PtaCase
{
    public decimal CaseId { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<CaseDetail> CaseDetails { get; set; }      
}

public class CaseDetail
{
    public decimal CaseId { get; set; }
     public virtual PtaCase Case { get; set; }
}
```

Entity Map

```
    public PtaCaseMap()
    {
        ToTable("USR_PTA_CASES");

        HasKey(c => c.CaseId);

        Property(c => c.CaseId)
          .HasColumnName("USR_CASE_ID");

           HasMany(p => p.CaseDetails)
            .WithRequired();           

    }

    public CaseDetailMap()
    {
        ToTable("USR_PTA_CASES_INFO");

        HasKey(p => new { p.CaseId, p.CaseTextSequence });

        Property(s => s.CaseId)
           .HasColumnName("USR_CASE_ID");

        Property(s => s.CaseTextSequence)
            .HasColumnName("USR_CASE_INFO_BLOCK_SEQ");

        Property(s => s.CaseTypeCode)
            .HasColumnName("USR_CASE_INFO_TYPE_CODE");

        Property(s => s.Text)
            .HasColumnName("USR_CASE_INFO_BLOCK_TEXT");         

    }

   public PtaSetDetailMap()
    {
        ToTable("USR_PTA_SET_DETAIL");

        HasKey(s => s.SetDetailId);

        Property(s => s.SetId)
            .HasColumnName("USR_SET_ID");


        Property(s => s.CaseId)
            .HasColumnName("USR_CASE_ID");

        Property(s => s.CaseSeq)
            .HasColumnName("USR_SLIDE_SEQ");

        Property(s => s.SetDetailId)
            .HasColumnName("USR_SET_DETAIL_ID");

            HasRequired(s => s.PtaCases)
            .WithMany()
            .HasForeignKey(s => s.CaseId);

    }
```

Code to retrieve data:

```
       var query = GetQuery<PtaSetDetail>(s => s.SetId == setId);

        if (onlyActive)
        {
            query = query.Where(s => s.ActiveFlag == "A");
        }

        if (includeCases)
        {
            var returnData = query
                                .Include(p => p.PtaCases)
                                .Include(p => p.PtaCases.CaseDetails)
                                 .ToList();

            return returnData.OrderBy(s => s.CaseSeq);
        }

        return query.ToList();
```

When we execute the above code we get only one record for CaseDetail entity but in database we see two entries. When we execute the query generated by entity framework, could see 10 records (contains two entries for case detail) but when its getting converted to Entity object we get only one CaseDetail.

Comment: You have a model problem. Both PtaSetDetail and PtaCase shouldn't have caseId as a property.  It appears that you are trying to implement a one-to-many relationship, but have it wrong (or maybe many-to-many)?

Comment: in PTACase Table caseid is a primary key and in set detail its a foreign key and has multiple case ids associated to set. i don't get any compile error, i get all the cases associated to the set detail but i don't get all CaseDetail (second level relation object)..

Comment: I see a PtaSetDetail can have many CaseDetails, but can a CaseDetail belong to multiple PtaSetDetails, or can it only belong to one?  In either case, you don't need a PtaCase class.

Comment: i need both  PTACase and Case details. I didnt include PTACase  just to get CaseDetails...

Comment: @RobertMcKee let me know if you need more details.. not sure whether i explained the scenario correctly.. thanks for your response...

Comment: Sorry, just trying to figure out what your model is.  Looks like you have a bunch of properties missing, and you reuse the name CaseId in multiple tables.  `CaseTextSequence` is missing from CaseDetails for example.

Answer (score 1):

In your `PtaCaseMap` you're missing an *inverse property*. You have ...

```
HasMany(p => p.CaseDetails).WithRequired();
```

... but it should be ...

```
HasMany(p => p.CaseDetails).WithRequired(cd => cd.Case);
```

The former mapping causes EF to infer that there are two separate associations between `Case` and `CaseDetails`. When EF creates the database, you'll see that `CaseDetails` will have an additional field `Case_CaseId`.

The corrected mapping uses `CaseDetails.CaseId` for both ends of the association.

So why do you get only one `CaseDetail`? I think that has to do with how the details were created. I think you created one of them while setting `CaseDetail.Case` --so the field `Case_Case_Id` was filled-- and another one by setting `CaseDetail.CaseId` --which set the field `Case_Id`. Only the last detail is pulled from the database when you include `PtaCase.CaseDetails`.